# Get current background color and reset it after .hover?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Using .hover to change the background on a menu. All the backgrounds are not the same color in the menu, so when the user hovers off I want the background color to return to the initial color.  (I want it to read the current background and then reset it after the hover.)

Below is what I have but it's not working.  I don't know how to get the second part of the hover script to accept the variable for background-color.

```
$('#dmenu ul li a').hover(

  function () {
var bgOn = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#efefef');
}, 
  function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', (bgOn);
}
);
```

Not a wiz with JQuery so I am sure it's something simple.  Thanks

Comment: You're overthinking this one a bit, I think.  This is a perfect task for CSS a:hover.  I'm a big jQuery fan, but I think it's probably overkill here.

Comment: Always go for CSS option first & if anything not possible through CSS then you can go for js. :)

Comment: I agree, but it's a special situation.  Hard to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bgOn;
$('#dmenu ul li a').hover(

  function () {
    bgOn = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#efefef');
}, 
  function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', bgOn);
}
);
```

in your example `bgOn` would be out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, which sets a `data-background-color-orig` attribute on hover with the original background color, while the callback simply restores the original background color using that attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjsDq/7/

I've done something similar to this in the past when both the to and from background colors for an element were dynamically generated, to account for lack of support for inline hover styles.

Relevant JS:

```
$('#dmenu ul li a').hover( function() {
    $(this).attr('data-background-color-orig', $(this).css('background-color'));
    $(this).css('background-color', '#EFEFEF');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-background-color-orig'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try mouseenter and mouseleave events to change the background colors.

You can also do it with css something like below

```
ul li a:hover
{
    //set background color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/AA5dK/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="products" href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a id="services" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #888}
#menu li {float:left;}
#menu a {display:block;padding:15px 35px;color:#fff}
#menu a:hover {background-color:#efefef;color:#888;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #fff}
#home {background-color:red;}
#products {background-color:orange;}
#services {background-color:green;}
#about {background-color:blue;}
```